# .htaccess mod-rewrite regex apache confusion results in 10k 404's per day

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have reviewed the many questions posted here related to `.htaccess`, `apache`, `mod-rewrite` and `regex`, but I'm just not getting it.  I tried a few different things but either I am over complicating things or making beginner mistakes. Regardless, I've been at it a few days now and have completely scrambled things somewhere as the 10000 404's per day are showing.

**My site**

I have a WordPress site which contains over 23,000 posts broken down into just over 1200 categories. The site features streaming video files, industry news, show reviews, movies, phpbb forums, etc. and is structured like this:

- site / base categories ( 0 and a-z) / sub categories (series name) /
  posts (episode name .html )for all streaming media episodes
- site / movies / post title.html for all streaming movies
- site / news / posttitle.html
- site / reviews / posttitle.html
- site / page.html for assorted pages
- site / forums

Permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%.html`

I have am using the Yoast Wordpress SEO plugin and have the option to append a trailing slash enabled for directories and categories.

here is the current `.htaccess`

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

**My examples**

From our old site structure we have many inbound links using "/episode title/".  This is wrong.  We need these incoming links to redirect to /watch-anime/letter, number or symbol only 1 character long/series title/episode title.html

```
/one-piece-episode-528​/
```

should be

```
/watch-anime/o/one-piece/​one-piece-episode-528​.html
```

A mistake I made caused this problem... "`/watch-anime/letter/series title/episode title/`" to "`/watch-anime/letter/series title/episode title.html`".  So, we need to remove trailing slash from single posts and add .html

```
/watch-anime​/w​/welcome-to-the-nhk​/welcome-to-the-nhk-episode-14​/
```

should be

```
/watch-anime​/w​/welcome-to-the-nhk​/welcome-to-the-nhk-episode-14​.html
```

The same mistake caused this problem when combined with the old site structure issue... "`/episode title.html`" needs to be "`/watch-anime/letter/series title/episode title.html`"

```
/one-piece-episode-528​.html
```

needs to be

```
/watch-anime/o/one-piece/​one-piece-episode-528​.html
```

As you can see, I've made a mess of things between migrating the sites post structure and my attempts to fix it.  I am now asking for any help you can provide in getting a proper .htaccess file that will take care of these 301 redirects.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Want to include your current .htaccess file in the question?

Comment: Please tell me those are NOT _spaces_ in your URI paths!

Comment: nope, no spaces in the URL's.  The current .htaccess is pretty default.  I pulled everything out when i couldn't get it to work.  I'll edit the post and provide some real examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if RewriteMap work with `.htaccess` files, but anyway here's my solution for virtual host, which should work flawlessly.

Create a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) file. See [here for more information](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). This is a very simple text file with: first, the wrong URL *without the '/'*, then **one space** (at least) and then the right url, like this:

```
one-piece-episode-528​ /watch-anime/o/one-piece/​one-piece-episode-528​.html
dexter-season-6-episode-1 /watch-interesting-stuff/d/dexter/dexter-season-6-episode-1.html
breaking-bad-full-season-3 /watch-interesting-stuff/b/breaking-bad/​breaking-bad-full-season-3.html
```

and so on.

convert this simple text file into hash map. For example:

```
httxt2dbm -i mapanime.txt -o mapanime.map
```

Now declare it in your vhost:

```
RewriteMap mapanime \
    dbm:/pathtofile/mapanime.map
```

So all in all your vhost should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap mapanime \
        dbm:/pathtofile/mapanime.map
    # don't touch the URL, but try to search if it exists in mapanime
    RewriteRule /([^/]*)/$ - [QSA,NC,E=VARANIME:${mapanime:$1|notfound}]
    # if VARANIME not empty *and*
    #   VARANIME different from "notfound":
    RewriteCond %{ENV:VARANIME} ^(notfound|)$
    # then redirect it to the right URL:
    # QSA = query string append
    # R = redirect, 301 = definitive redirect
    # L = last = don't go further
    RewriteRule . %{ENV:VARANIME} [QSA,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps.

I don't see a simpler solution, but I'm pretty sure this one will work.

If it doesn't work: read my usual "two hints", and add the rewrite log in your question.

### Two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Thank you very much for this!  I have a question though.  When creating the map file, will I need to add a single line for every post on the site?  we are over 21,000 posts now and if I do this for each one, the file will have over 84,000 lines as I try to account for each of the three possible wrong url's.  Perhaps I am once again over complicating things.  Kudo's on the Dexter reference.  lol.  It could have only been better if you had used "Breaking Bad" instead.

Comment: The bad news is that... **`yes`** you'll have to dump your whole corresponding datas. But thanks to mysql this should be a child's game. Exemple: drop all the short links: `mysql -u username -ppassword wordpressdatabasename -e "select post_name from wp_posts order by post_name;"`

Comment: If you want to drop them into a file: `mysql -u username -ppassword wordpressdatabasename -e "select post_name from wp_posts order by post_name;" >> filename`. Then just work on that file. If I were your flatmate this would take me a few minutes to do the whole job (my answer + correct rewritemap file).

Comment: Drop me a message on my blog (see my profile) (any post should be fine) and I'd be gla to help you!

Comment: I really appreciate the help Oliver.  Thanks!  I will be reviewing your linked material and giving this a shot.  I will let you know ASAP how it worked out and may very well take you up on your offer for assistance!  Is there an English version of your blog available?

Comment: Nope sorry, but I'm working on it... It's very long. Drop me a message anywhere on any articles it'll be fine.