# mod_rewrite espression for multi client application

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a php application that serves multiple customers. Code is placed in the domain's root and is shared for all customers. Each customer can access it's page by using query string parameter "id".

I need advice and a sample code how to achieve this routing via mod_rewrite or it' better way to do it through php routing script:

**Home page**:

```
www.example.com/customerA --> www.example.com/customerA/main?id=1
www.example.com/customerB --> www.example.com/customerB/main?id=4
```

Note: "main" is `main.php` file not displaying file extensions.
Customer subfolders are not the real ones.

**Inner pages** are using additional parameters like:

```
www.example.com/customerA/page1?id=1&par1=5
```

On *SERVER SIDE* all rewrites should be interpreted as `www.example.com/main?id=4` 
without virtual subfolder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/customerA /customerA/main?id=1 [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/customerB /customerB/main?id=4 [QSA,NC,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/(customer(A|B))/main /main [QSA,NC]
```

Now that's I've answered precisely to your question, I'm pretty sure it's not what you want.
If you have a lot of customers, I've made a huge answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610507/htaccess-mod-rewrite-regex-apache-confusion-results-in-10k-404s-per-day/8614097#8614097) of a question that was about films, but you it's about customers, but the principle is exactly the same.

---

If you want to be more generic:

```
# if URL is not a real file...
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# if URL is not a real folder...
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
# ...and if adding "php" points to a real file...
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
# ...then rewrite internally with "php" extension:
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [QSA,NC]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since I don't have a lot of customers the priciple is OK. But it seems it's not working as desired. I would like to use more dynamic rewrite rule for the used php files. Now you encoded "main" which is actually main.php into the rule. Is there a way to use any of the *.php files in the rule.

Comment: Modified my answer. Hope this is ok **`;)`**