# how to redirect all dynamic urls to home page using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As i am upgrading my old site to new server. since my old site is having so many dynamic urls im planning to redirect all those dynamic urls to static urls. As i have succeeded in redirecting some of my dynamic urls to static but the issue here is i have some around 5000 dynamic urls. So i want to redirect all dynamic urls to home page using .htaccess. How to achieve this. Can any one help me in this regard.

My dynamic Url Structure is like this `http://www.mysite.com/play.php?id=4818`

I have redirected some around 50 urls to static using the following structure.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=4818$
RewriteRule ^play\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/play/Dinos_Egg_Hatch? [R=301,L]
```

Now my objective is to redirect all urls except the already redirected urls to home page.

Any idea?

Comment: How do you know which URLs are already redirected? A list? A filter? A regular expression? How? You question is very vague.

Comment: @ Olivier Pons : I already have some of my urls which are my bookmarked urls so i redirected those urls to static...

Comment: not static, they are dynamic but they are our own games urls. if the user bookmarked those urls i dont want ot loose the traffic from those urls.please tell me how to redirect all dynamic urls to home page(index.php)

Comment: I could help you if you precise exactly **all** the URLs you want the use to type in the browser, and **how** they should be internally modified in the server.

Comment: For example take a look at the url structure..http://www.mysite.com/play.php?id=1, http://www.mysite.com/play.php?id=2 ... http://www.mysite.com/play.php?id=n where n=some highest number like 5000. So i want these dynamic urls to this home page http://www.mysite.com/

Comment: You almost answered! Now, please update your question, with what you've said, and precise (once again) exactly all the URLs you want the use to type in the browser, and how they should be internally modified in the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9182/discussion-between-phphunger-and-olivier-pons)

Answer (score 9):

If you have a lot of redirections, I've made a huge answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610507/htaccess-mod-rewrite-regex-apache-confusion-results-in-10k-404s-per-day/8614097#8614097) of a question that was about films, but you it's about redirections, but the principle is exactly the same.

---

After the long chat we had, I put the solution:

You had tons of redirections like that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=4177$
RewriteRule ^play\.php$ http://www.diz.com/play/Game1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=4195$
RewriteRule ^play\.php$ http://www.diz.com/play/Game2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=4303$
RewriteRule ^play\.php$ http://www.diz.com/play/Game3 [R=301,L]

...............
```

I've dumped in a file ALL the URLs you want to redirect. Like this:

```
4177 Game1
4195 Game2
......
```

and so on.

I've converted this simple text file into hash map. Like this:

```
httxt2dbm -i dynamic.txt -o dynamic.map
```

Now i've done this rewrite rules in my vhost for test and they worked:

```
RewriteMap dynamic \
    dbm:/pathtofile/dynamic.map

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([0-9]+)(&|$)
# if condition met, don't touch the URL but set an environment variable:
RewriteRule ^play\.php$ - [E=DYNAMIC:${dynamic:%2|}]

# if environment variable not empty = found => redirect:
RewriteCond %{ENV:DYNAMIC} !^$ 
RewriteRule ^play\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/play/%{ENV:DYNAMIC} [R=301,L]
```

NB: you told me you have your own server. That's why I've made this answer, and **you'll have to add these rewriterules in your `vhost` file, not in your `htaccess` file otherwise it won't work**

---

Now, instead of more than 100 rewrite rules hack, you have 5 nice rewrite rules and it's dynamic: if you want to add another redirection, just add in `dynamic.txt` your game, and re-compile it:

```
httxt2dbm -i dynamic.txt -o dynamic.map
```

No need to restart the server, it should work flawlessly!!!

Hope this helped!