# Does Robots Meta Tag No Index remove indexed URL's

Tags: url-rewriting, seo, duplicates, google-search-console

We have an application which has about 15000 pages. For better SEO reasons we had to change the URL's. Google had already crawled all of these pages earlier and due to the change, we see a lot of duplicate titles/meta description on webmasters. Our impressions on google have dropped and we believe this is the reason. Correct me if my assumption is incorrect. Now we are not able to write a regular expression for the change of URL's using a 301 redirect, because the change was such. The only way to do it would be to write 301 redirects for individual URL's which is not feasible for 10000 URL's. Now can we use a robots meta tag with NOINDEX? **My question basically is if I write a NOINDEX metatag will google remove the already indexed URL's?** If not what are the other ways to remove the old indexed URL's from google? ANother thing which I can do is make all the previous pages 404 errors to avoid the duplicates, but will that be a right thing to do?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now we are not able to write a regular expression for the change of
>   URL's using a 301 redirect, because the change was such. The only way
>   to do it would be to write 301 redirects for individual URL's which is
>   not feasible for 10000 URL's.

Of course you can! I'm rewriting more than 15000 URLs with mod_rewrite and RewriteMap!
This is just a matter of scripting / echo all URLs and mastering vim, but you can, and easily. If you need more information, just ask.

What you can do is a RewriteMap fils like this:

```
/baskinrobbins/branch/branch1/ /baskinrobbins/branch/Florida/Jacksonville/branch1
```

I've made a huge answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610507/htaccess-mod-rewrite-regex-apache-confusion-results-in-10k-404s-per-day/8614097#8614097) and you can very easily adapt it to your needs.

I could do that job in 1-2 hours max but I'm expensive **`;)`**.

Comment: Let me give you an example: earlier one of my url was /baskinrobbins/branch/branch1/ which has now been changed to /baskinrobbins/branch/Florida/Jacksonville/branch1/ . Now how do I write a redirect rule, when I cannot determine the city and area based on just /baskinrobbins/branch/branch1/ unless I hit the server side code.

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope this helps. Don't hesitate to leave a message on my blog if you want to contact me.

Comment: I guess I was not clear now for baskinrobbin /baskinrobbins/branch/branch1/ has to redirect to /baskinrobbins/branch/Florida/Jacksonville/branch1
but maybe for kfc /kfc/branch/branch1/ has to redirect to /kfc/branch/NewYork/Delaware/branch1 which means that a regular expression cannot be written and also if I have to rewrite each url manually, I cannot generate some file and do it. I would have to manually check each and every URL to see what URL it should be redirected to and then do it. Definitely not a 1-2 hrs job :(

Comment: I don't know about your whole stuff but a nice sql query with output to a file, then a big use of macros with `vim` has always done the job faster than expected. Maybe not 1-2 hours, but I'm pretty sure a few hours should do the job. Let's chat I'll see what I can do `;)`

Comment: We are a small startup with no funding :( so I dont think I would be able to afford you. However some insights on this on the actual question would be highly appreciated : My question basically is if I write a NOINDEX metatag for all the old urls will google remove the already indexed URL's?

Comment: I don't know. I just know that you have to keep in mind that google re-indexing is always a *slow* process (3-8 weeks) so if you've moved the URLs, if I were you, I would just do a 404 with (1) a suggestion to the correct link (2) a link to the main page. Google should sort the whole stuff on his own. But don't take my advice as the best one. I would do this if I were you, that's all **`;)`**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9350/discussion-between-olivier-pons-and-maxim-dsouza)

Comment: I'm in the chat room waiting for you

Answer (score 0):

**Reindexing is slow**

It would take weeks for Google to ignore the older URLs anyways.

**Use Htaccess 301 redirects**

You can add a file on your Apache server, called `.htaccess`, that is able to list all the old URLs and the new URLs and have the user instantly redirected to the new page. Can you generate such a text file? I'm sure you can loop through the sections in your app or whatever and generate a list of URLs.

Use the following syntax.

```
 Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html 
 Redirect 301 /oldpage2.html http://www.yoursite.com/folder/
```

This prevents the 404 File Not Found errors, and is better than the meta refresh or redirect tag because the the old page is not even served to clients.

I did this for a website that had gone through a recent upgrade, and since google kept pointing to the older files, we needed to redirect clients to view the new content instead.

**Where's .htaccess?**

Go to your site’s root folder, and create/download the `.htaccess` file to your local computer and edit it with a plain-text editor (ie. Notepad). If you are using FTP Client software and you don’t see any .htaccess file on your server, ensure you are viewing  invisible / system files.

Comment: Hello @Geotarget, Thanks for your repsonse. However writing a 301 redirect is not feasible, because it is a dynamic application where pages are getting added daily and the change was such that writing a regular expression for all these changes is practically impossible. The only way to write 301 redirects would be to write it manually for more than 10000 pages which would be a real pain. We would have to look into each and every url to check if a 301 is required or not.

Comment: You have said "Can you generate such a text file? I'm sure you can loop through the sections in your app or whatever and generate a list of URLs." But I cannot figure out how to do that. I would appreciate it, if you could explain further on generating the URL's. Thanks