# Fetch parameters in any order

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Given a site that has URLs like these:

```
http://example.com/catalogue
http://example.com/catalogue/category-20
http://example.com/catalogue/customer-5
http://example.com/catalogue/category-20/customer-5
http://example.com/catalogue/customer-5/category-20
```

... is there a sensible mod_rewrite-only way to make internal redirects to:

```
http://example.com/catalogue.php
http://example.com/catalogue.php?category_id=20
http://example.com/catalogue.php?customer_id=5
http://example.com/catalogue.php?category_id=20&customer_id=5
http://example.com/catalogue.php?customer_id=5&category_id=20
```

...?

My attempts are getting me nowhere:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)category-(\d+)(.*)$   $1$3?category_id=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)customer-(\d+)(.*)$   $1$3?customer_id=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^catalogue/?$               catalogue.php [L,QSA]
# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
# configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit 
# if necessary

RewriteRule ^(.*/)category-(\d+)(.*)$   $1$3?category_id=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)customer-(\d+)(.*)$   $1$3?customer_id=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^catalogue/?                catalogue.php [L,QSA]
# Matches everything that starts with /catalogue (not intended)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
RewriteRule ^/catalogue(.*)(/category-([0-9]+))(.*) \
  /catalogue$1$4?category_id=$3 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/catalogue(.*)(/customer-([0-9]+))(.*) \
  /catalogue$1$4?customer_id=$3 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/catalogue/?$ /catalogue.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

If it doesn't work try without the **`/`**:

```
RewriteRule ^catalogue(.*)(/category-([0-9]+))(.*) \
  /catalogue$1$4?category_id=$3 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^catalogue(.*)(/customer-([0-9]+))(.*) \
  /catalogue$1$4?customer_id=$3 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^catalogue/?$ /catalogue.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

---

Test with `/catalogue/`:

```
  1  (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /catalogue/
  2  (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue/(category-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/' 
  3  (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue/(customer-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/' 
  4  (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue/?$' to uri '/catalogue/' 
  5  (2) rewrite '/catalogue/' -> '/catalogue.php'
  6  (2) local path result: /catalogue.php
  7  (2) prefixed with document_root to /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php
  8  (1) go-ahead with /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php [OK]
```

---

Test with `/catalogue/category-54`:

```
  1 (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /catalogue/category-54
  2 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue(.*)(/category-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/category-54'
  3 (2) rewrite '/catalogue/category-54' -> '/catalogue?category_id=54'
  4 (3) split uri=/catalogue?category_id=54 -> uri=/catalogue, args=category_id=54
  5 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue(.*)(/customer-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue'
  6 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue/?$' to uri '/catalogue'
  7 (2) rewrite '/catalogue' -> '/catalogue.php'
  8 (2) local path result: /catalogue.php
  9 (2) prefixed with document_root to /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php
 10 (1) go-ahead with /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php [OK]
```

---

Test with `/catalogue/customer-128`:

```
  1 (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /catalogue/customer-128
  2 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue(.*)(/category-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/customer-128'
  3 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue(.*)(/customer-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/customer-128'
  4 (2) rewrite '/catalogue/customer-128' -> '/catalogue?customer_id=128'
  5 (3) split uri=/catalogue?customer_id=128 -> uri=/catalogue, args=customer_id=128
  6 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue/?$' to uri '/catalogue'
  7 (2) rewrite '/catalogue' -> '/catalogue.php'
  8 (2) local path result: /catalogue.php
  9 (2) prefixed with document_root to /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php
 10 (1) go-ahead with /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php [OK]
```

---

Test with `/catalogue/category-54/customer-128`:

```
  1 (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /catalogue/category-54/customer-128
  2 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue(.*)(/category-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/category-54/customer-128'
  3 (2) rewrite '/catalogue/category-54/customer-128' -> '/catalogue/customer-128?category_id=54'
  4 (3) split uri=/catalogue/customer-128?category_id=54 -> uri=/catalogue/customer-128, args=category_id=54
  5 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue(.*)(/customer-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/customer-128'
  6 (2) rewrite '/catalogue/customer-128' -> '/catalogue?customer_id=128'
  7 (3) split uri=/catalogue?customer_id=128 -> uri=/catalogue, args=customer_id=128&category_id=54
  8 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue/?$' to uri '/catalogue'
  9 (2) rewrite '/catalogue' -> '/catalogue.php'
 10 (2) local path result: /catalogue.php
 11 (2) prefixed with document_root to /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php
 12 (1) go-ahead with /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php [OK]
```

---

Test with `/catalogue/customer-128/category-54`:

```
  1 (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /catalogue/customer-128/category-54
  2 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue(.*)(/category-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/customer-128/category-54'
  3 (2) rewrite '/catalogue/customer-128/category-54' -> '/catalogue/customer-128?category_id=54'
  4 (3) split uri=/catalogue/customer-128?category_id=54 -> uri=/catalogue/customer-128, args=category_id=54
  5 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue(.*)(/customer-([0-9]+))(.*)' to uri '/catalogue/customer-128'
  6 (2) rewrite '/catalogue/customer-128' -> '/catalogue?customer_id=128'
  7 (3) split uri=/catalogue?customer_id=128 -> uri=/catalogue, args=customer_id=128&category_id=54
  8 (3) applying pattern '^/catalogue/?$' to uri '/catalogue'
  9 (2) rewrite '/catalogue' -> '/catalogue.php'
 10 (2) local path result: /catalogue.php
 11 (2) prefixed with document_root to /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php
 12 (1) go-ahead with /home/olivier/Documents/website/catalogue.php [OK]
```

---

### Two hints:

If you're **not** in a hosted environment (= if it's *your own server* and *you **can** modify the virtual hosts*, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Perhaps I should have explained that my idea of *sensible* is not needing to repeat the whole rule-set for each page in the site. Since there're only a few global GET parameters, I had expected to fetch them in a prior stage.

Comment: My first sample shows how to do this: whatever the order, it first test if there's a parameter, and if so, add in the `GET` and removes it from the URL. Then it does this once again with the second parameter. Then **only at the last test** it does the final '**`L`**' condition to stop rewriting. This is a nice way to have mixed parameters in the URL, **and to ignore the order of those parameters**. There are very few people who do this, but it works flawlessly **`;)`**

Comment: So, if you have say 4-5 different parameters in the URL, you can handle all of them in 4-5 lines, and the nice thing is that if some of them are missing they won't be in the `GET` parameters. Ain't life beautiful like this?

Comment: Your first rule-set is similar to mine except that you've hard-coded the URL fragment that corresponds to the page, and I get an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok you are right. I've updated my answer and add all my test logs to show that it works perfectly **`;)`**

Comment: I'm sure it works for you, but it doesn't work for me, neither in our shared dev server nor in my local computer, not even with hard-coded paths :( I suppose it's time to post logs here.

Comment: Edited: added my two usual hints at the end ;). And waiting for your log in your question ;)

Comment: Alright, your second rule-set does work for me if I use it in the site's root directory (which is acceptable). Any idea on how to remove the hard-coded `catalogue` bit so I get a generic rule?

Comment: It's much more complicated. You may have to lookup with a RewriteMap file. I've made a huge answer for something else, but you may see the "big picture" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610507/htaccess-mod-rewrite-regex-apache-confusion-results-in-10k-404s-per-day/8614097#8614097 . If my question was ok don't hesitate to check it as valid **`;)`**